# Namespace Confusion

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I have a WPF app that I am trying to convert to a DLL. The problem is that I have a number of application level resources set up in my App.XAML. In the dll I am trying to set my resources programatically.

To load my resources programatically I have this:

```
ResourceDictionary myResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("C:\\Users\\Ash\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\moo Process Flow Manager\\moo Process Flow Manager\\Resources\\Styles\\Shared.xaml");
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
myResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("C:\\Users\\Ash\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\moo Process Flow Manager\\moo Process Flow Manager\\Resources\\Styles\\ToolBar.xaml");
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
myResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("C:\\Users\\Ash\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\moo Process Flow Manager\\moo Process Flow Manager\\Resources\\Styles\\ZoomBox.xaml");
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
```

This line:

```
myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("C:\\Users\\Ash\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\moo Process Flow Manager\\moo Process Flow Manager\\Resources\\Styles\\ZoomBox.xaml");
```

Throws the following error at runtime:

```
'Failed to create a 'Type' from the text 's:ZoomBox'.' Line number '5' and line position '12'.
```

With the inner exception:

```
{"Type reference cannot find type named '{clr-namespace:Arkitec.moo.ProcessFlowManager.Controls}ZoomBox'."}
```

Here is the line thats causing the error within zoombox.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:Arkitec.moo.ProcessFlowManager.Controls">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type s:ZoomBox}">
```

Here is where the class is declared that it should be looking at in zoombox.cs:

```
namespace Arkitec.moo.ProcessFlowManager.Controls
{
    public class ZoomBox : Control
    {
```

Please let me know if you need anymore information.

EDIT: As per Guilammes answert I tried:

```
myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("Resources/Styles/Shared.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

But get the following error:

```
Cannot locate resource 'resources/styles/shared.xaml'.
```

Comment: I deleted my answer since, you edit your question.I Hope someone will help you more

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the shared.xaml property as follow:

```
Build Action --> Page
copy to output directory --> do not copy
custom tool --> MSBuild:Compile
```

then refer the xaml as follow

```
new System.Uri("/YourNamespace;Resources/Styles/Shared.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
```